# What is the best practice to offer users to have his own sub-domain? Sub-Domain or Sub-folders?

Tags: web, subdomain

I am new in this kind of situation. I must implement a site in php that will have a URL like "mycompany.com". I would like to offer the possibility the users to create his own url inside my site. So user David could have 2 options: 1-Using  sub-domains "david.mycompany.com" or 2- Using sub-folders "mycompany.com/david". I see people prefer to use sub-domain for this kind of situation. But what is wrong whit the second one? What is the best practice and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foo.bar.com` is a subdomain
`bar.com/foo` is a directory under the domain.

If you are offering subdomain,
then there is absolutely nothing wrong with offering `foo.bar.com`

There can be permission issues inside your VM.
If you set the permission correctly and jail them and give them
correct privileges, there should be an issue.

for jailing, refer to :
http://how-to.linuxcareer.com/how-to-automatically-chroot-jail-selected-ssh-user-logins